# перехват WM_NCPAINT - дорисовка кнопки в заголовок

Tags: c++, winapi

Не теряю надежды всунуть кнопку в неклиентскую область, проблема возникает при попытке и мою кнопку отображать, и стандартный заголовок. Пока получается только что-то одно :)

```
if (Message == WM_NCPAINT) {
    //  DefWindowProc(hwnd, Message, wparam, lparam);
        HDC hdc;
        RECT rect;
        HBRUSH b;
        HPEN pe;
        hdc = GetDCEx(hwnd, (HRGN)wparam, DCX_WINDOW | DCX_CACHE | DCX_INTERSECTRGN | DCX_LOCKWINDOWUPDATE);
        GetWindowRect(hwnd, &rect);
        b = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0, 180, 180));
        SelectObject(hdc,b);
        pe = CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 1, RGB(90, 90, 90));
        SelectObject(hdc, pe);
        Rectangle(hdc, 50, 2, 60, 12);
        ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc);
        RedrawWindow(hwnd, &rect, (HRGN)wparam, RDW_UPDATENOW);
        return 0;
    }
```

Такая обработка сообщения рисует в неклиентской области прямоугольник,но при попытке нарисовать перед этим стандартный заголовок (раскоментировав)  `DefWindowProc(hwnd, Message, wparam, lparam);` приводит к тому что мой прямоугольник больше не рисуется. Это как-то можно поправить?

Comment: Попробуйте использовать вместо `GetDCEx` - `GetWindowDC` или просто уберите лишние флаги, оставив только `DCX_WINDOW`. Т.е., суть в том, что регион отрисовки после `DefWindowProc` уже обновлен.

Comment: @mega не помогло :-/

Comment: Сделайте простой тест, без лишнего кода: `DefWindowProc(...) -> hdc=GetWindowDC(hwnd) -> Rectangle(hdc, 0, 0, 10, 10) -> ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc)`

Comment: @mega все равно не рисует.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По всей видимости, у Вас работает композитная тема, которая дорисовывает все окна на уровне драйвера (например делает blur-эффект). У меня в таком случае работает вот такой метод:

```
switch (message)
{
...
case WM_NCPAINT:
    //DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    hdc = ::GetWindowDC(hWnd);
    ::SendMessage(hWnd, WM_PRINT, WPARAM(hdc), PRF_NONCLIENT);
    ::Rectangle(hdc, 0, 0, 10, 10);
    ::ReleaseDC(hWnd, hdc);
    break;
...
default:
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
return 0;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но blur-эффект, конечно тут уже теряется. Самому был бы интересен вариант с учетом спецэффектов.

Comment: Спасибо огромное, получилось!  Сначала не поняла что defWinProc вообще не нужен вначале.

Comment: Он тут только для аналогии с Вашим кодом )